# Should code files have a BOM or not?

Tags: encoding, byte-order-mark

I am starting out on a new project, and I want to know what encoding I should choose for my code files.

I am writing a web app in Python + JavaScript + HTML + CSS on Linux, and my code editors Notepad++ and KomodoEdit give me some options:

- Encode in ANSI
- Encode in UTF-8 without BOM
- Encode in UTF-8

I am not sure which encoding should I choose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer could depend upon the operating system and versions of software (in particular, version of Python) you are using, but I would choose "Encode in UTF-8 without BOM"

In practice I would avoid using non-ASCII characters in source code. If you need them, use them only in string literals and in comments.

<sup>Avoid having them in identifiers.</sup>

Comment: why is it that the encoding choice depends on Python version?

Comment: I would guess that Python 3 might understand the BOM in source code, but not yet Python 2.7 (but I may be wrong).

Answer (score 0):

Better use UTF-8 as its a web application, the UTF-8 support almost all the browsers and operating systems.